# how can i access the user part of the result coming from facebook authentication?

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase, with popup Facebook authentication.

Code is very similar to what the Firebase documentation has, but I am unable to get the Facebook user, although I am able to get the token.

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("Successful login using FB.");
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>user : " + user);
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>token : " + token);
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("masuk dalam error catch");

  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;

  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>error code: " + error.code);
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>error message: " + error.message);
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>error email: " + error.email);
  $("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>error credential: " + error.credential);


  // ...
});
})
```

This is the screen output in my browser. As you can see, user prints [object Object], but token prints fine. Am I missing something there?

Thank you

```
Login with Facebook Trial

DEBUG MESSAGE: Successful login using FB.
user : [object Object]
token :     EAAatbKAtNvYBAG6Ts0IZAZCRTbQwRpZAeIU4gRed3ORhPhUKrmBvdc4l1fkfYx2TuFDH75BpxA4BIchCiA2uq6OjaZCO1UM1xSOwsKgGDsbjzTF6ZCgq2r5BVwYoSdvDJoJ8D7cx6EvxA3zsimKMlc4IYBzJLBHZBXtbzZAEX8oOgZDZD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `result.user` is a complex object, so when you add it to the HTML your browser shows `[object Object]`.

But you can access properties of the [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object:

```
$("#DEBUGMSG").append("<br>user : " + user.displayName);
```

Comment: I see, that was what I was missing. Thank you so much Frank, it works fine now!

Comment: Just did both of those things. Cheers.